# Linq Fetch all controls (ordered)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

Is there a way to fetch all the control using linq.

What I'll like to do is something like that (order the control by tab index) :

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls.OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex)
{
    ...
}
```

I use that kind of query when I got a List<...>

I use c# and .Net 3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ControlCollection` only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. That's easy to fix though - add a call to `Cast()`:

```
foreach (Control control in Controls.Cast<Control>()
                                    .OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
{
}
```

Or you could use a query expression, which will call `Cast()` where necessary:

```
var controls = from Control c in Controls
               orderby c.TabIndex
               select c;

foreach (Control control in controls)
{
}
```

Comment: Note: TabIndex is on WebControl, so replace all "Control" with "WebControl".

Comment: TabIndex is also on WinControl.

Thx for that quick answer!